# Style specific table without affecting every table

Tags: css

I have the following css for one of my tables:

```
.customer-table tr, td, th {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Everything looks really even and beautiful.
[image]
However, when I write my CSS like this, all the tables on my website get affected by this stylesheet and they have 2px wide black borders.
Then I tried to change my CSS like this:

```
table.customer-table {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

tr.customer-table {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

td.customer-table {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

th.customer-table {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

And gave every table element this CSS class. Now the table is all screwed up. 
[image]

Why is the space some cells have, now different?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: It's worth noting that your two different sets of styles are not equivalent. The first style `.customer-table tr, td, th` will apply to only `<tr>` elements with the `customer-table` class and _all_ `<td>` and `<th>` elements. Your second set will assume that _every_ element has the `customer-table` class, which is extremely unlikely.

Comment: The first rule targets every `tr` in the table with the class of `.customer-table`, every `td` and `th` on the page regardless of class. The second set of rules does things differently.
This targets the `table` with the class, the `tr` with the class, the `td` with the class, and the `th` with the class. The two sets are not equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this. Now the `th`, `tr` and `td` **have to** be a descendant of an element with the class `.customer-table`.

```
.customer-table th,
.customer-table tr,
.customer-table td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Your first example targeted any element with the class `.customer-table`, any `th`, any `tr` and any `td`. The `th`, `tr` and `td` were not being *"scoped"* by the `.customer-table` class and were free to affect any like element on the page.

As far as the spacing on the cells, we'd need to see the complete CSS and some markup. Based on your screenshots I can see that there are additional styles that you have not shared being applied to your table elements.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, and thanks a lot for your explanation as well!